# Handling "int java.util.List.size()" Error ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have data that I receive from a server and the receiving part goes well. But when there is no data is gives this error `int java.util.List.size()` which I know means that there is no data.

I tried handling with `get Count` but it still gives me an error, so I decided to ask help from here. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

This is my code:

```
  private void DataFound(){
    final ArrayAdapter<DataObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataObject>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.data_item, searchResults){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);


            DataObject searchResult = searchResults.get(position);

            title.setText(searchResult.getTitle());

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    if(adapter.getCount() == 0){
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: place your full code so i can help you, from where searchResults is coming to this method ,

Comment: `java.util.List.size()` in not an error message. Post the full error.

Comment: And please show your error stacktrace

Comment: Hey guys I found the issue thanks to your comments, I looked back and checked the source of the data and I had to handle it there. I just wanted to thank you guys,sorry for the dumb question haha. You guys deserve an upvote each! :D

Comment: The stackoverflow way would be to post an answer on what resolved the issue, and mark yourself as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking what seems to be a `java.util.List` with the search results, you should do this in a defensive and bullet proof manner. There should be two checks:

- Check, if the results list is not null.
- Check, if the results list is not empty.
- If it is empty, provide an understandable message with some suggestions to the end user on how the user can improve the search results, ideally with some examples.

Here is an dummy example on how you could do it:

```
private void dataFound(){

    List<SearchResult> searchResults = ...
    final ArrayAdapter<DataObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataObject>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.data_item, searchResults){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);

            if(searchResults != null && !searchResults.isEmpty()) {
                DataObject searchResult = searchResults.get(position);
                title.setText(searchResult.getTitle());
            }
            else {
                title.setText("No search results available. Please try again with another input, like e.g: 'foo' or 'bar'");
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    };

    if(adapter.getCount() == 0){
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private static class SearchResult {
    private String title;

    public SearchResult(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your adapter like below:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataObject> {
    private List<DataObject> dataObjectList;

    public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, int resourceId) {
        super(context, resourceId);
        this.dataObjectList= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setDataObjectList(List<DataObject> dataObjectList) {
        this.dataObjectList= dataObjectList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            DataObject searchResult = dataObjectList.get(position);
            title.setText(searchResult.getTitle());
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataObjectList.size();
    }
}
```

Initialize and set data to adapter like below:

```
private void dataFound() {
        List<SearchResult> searchResults = ...
        if (searchResults != null && !searchResults.isEmpty()) {
            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.your_layout);
            adapter.setDataObjectList(searchResults);
        } else {
            // give error message
        }
    }
```

That way you don't have to worry about list with zero items.

Answer (score 0):

Please set condition like this 
if(searchResults!=null && searchResults.size()>0){
*set adapter*
}
else{
*show toast*
}